# JavaScript - Optimizing autocomplete with debounce and throttling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, throttling, debouncing

I have the following text box and "autocomplete" function. It is supposed to have a debounce of 350 ms after every character is typed in the text box, but it doesn't work.

Try it for yourself in the JSFiddle. As you can see in the console, the console is logging every character typed without waiting for the debounce time.

What should I do to make this function work as intended? I want there to be a 350 ms debounce time to prevent every character from being logged... just update the output every 350ms.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8pdb97wj/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let debounce;
  $('.searchBox').on('keydown', function(e) {
    // get keycode of current keypress event
    var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);

    // do nothing if it's an arrow key or enter
    if (code == 37 || code == 38 || code == 39 || code == 40 || code == 13) {
      return;
    }

    // do normal behavior for any other key
    debounce = setTimeout(() => {
      getAutocomplete();
    }, 350);
  });
});

function getAutocomplete() {
  console.log($('.searchBox').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="searchBox"></input>
```

Comment: seems you forgot to clear the timeout. Without clearing, all you're doing is delaying the result by 350ms, not reducing the number of times the result happens.

Comment: The debounce doesn't work, which is what I'm trying to fix. The console is logging every character when it should be skipping and logging the input of the text box every 350ms, not every character

Comment: Kevin, how do you clear the timeout? That's exactly what I need to fix, thank you!

Comment: add `clearTimeout(debounce)` before your timeout

Comment: Please note, this is a debounce, not a throttle. The result will be it won't perform the action untill no event occurs for 350ms. If you want a throttle, the logic is a bit different.

Comment: Excellent, the debounce clearing works! Feel free to post your response as an answer and I'll give you credit for the question. If you add the throttling to the answer as well I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear the existing timeout before setting another one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let debounce;
  $('.searchBox').on('keydown', function(e) {
    // get keycode of current keypress event
    var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);

    // do nothing if it's an arrow key or enter
    if (code == 37 || code == 38 || code == 39 || code == 40 || code == 13) {
      return;
    }

    // do normal behavior for any other key
    clearTimeout(debounce);
    debounce = setTimeout(() => {
      getAutocomplete();
    }, 350);
  });
});

function getAutocomplete() {
  console.log($('.searchBox').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="searchBox">
```